# Is avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.34 supported by the Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to cast a video with that codec and I get this error:

```
The type provided ('video/mp2t; codecs="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.34"') is 
unsupported.
```

Is it supposed to be supported?

Thanks.

Comment: May be not, you can double check this list of [supported media](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media). You can change yours to a supported media to make it work.

Comment: While they now list all the avc.... codecs, often when I've asked I've been asked to convert the manifest to one that they support and that works so I was hoping to get a response from Google with that info.